# Laravel : Where do I rewrite auth() in Router.php?

Tags: laravel

There is a `auth()` method in `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php`,
I want to rewrite some routes in `auth()` method.

**Question:**

Where do I put the `auth()` method that I edit? 
If editing it in `Router.php`,it will be reset after `composer update`.

Answer (score 2):

You should never change the code inside the `vendor/` folder.

Calling `Auth:routes()` In your `routes/web.php` file will generate all 9 routes for the authentication part. I think there is no way to tell the method that you want to generate just some routes. Instead you can set them manually and change every route like you wish:

```
// Login Routes...
    Route::get('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm']);
    Route::post('login', ['as' => 'login.post', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login']);
    Route::post('logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@logout']);

// Registration Routes...
    Route::get('register', ['as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm']);
    Route::post('register', ['as' => 'register.post', 'uses' => 'Auth\RegisterController@register']);

// Password Reset Routes...
    Route::get('password/reset', ['as' => 'password.reset', 'uses' => 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm']);
    Route::post('password/email', ['as' => 'password.email', 'uses' => 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail']);
    Route::get('password/reset/{token}', ['as' => 'password.reset.token', 'uses' => 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm']);
    Route::post('password/reset', ['as' => 'password.reset.post', 'uses' => 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset']);
});
```